# CGI FieldStorage() or Database? Web-Scraping

Tags: python, forms, web-scraping, cgi

I am trying to pass user input from an html form to another form online. Is this possible? I tried to save cgi.FieldStorage() values in variables, and pass the variables to a script that completes the online form, but had no success.  All the information I have read on CGI has used CGI to merely output the FieldStorage() values on an html page.

Answer (score 0):

urllib/urllib2 have methods for this purpose. Below is a simple example:

```
import cgi, urllib, urllib2

# urlencode cgi data (assumes no duplicate fields)
data = {}
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
for key in form.keys():
    data[key] = form[key].value
data = urllib.urlencode(data)

# post the data to a remote form
page = urllib2.urlopen('http://post/form', data)
```

If you are doing this in production there are other considerations, but this is the general idea.

Also see the [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library.